# onCreateView() isn't called immediately after FragmentTransaction.commit()

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-fragments

I have an activity where I dynamically replace fragments:

```
private void goToFragment(Fragment newFragment, String tag) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment, tag);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Now, I want to access the views inside the fragment so I can put data (that I have stored in my activity) into them, immediately after calling `goToFragment`.

The problem is, the fragment's `onCreateView` isn't called before the fragment is rendered completely, at least to my understanding.

I know overriding the `onAttach(Activity activity)` in the fragment is one way to go about it, but then I have to cast it specifically to my activity - and I just want to avoid that because I consider it bad practice for the fragment to be dependent on a specific activity.

As far as I can see, `Fragment` doesn't have any listeners (as a subject) implemented.

So I figure I have to make my own listener (Using the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) to make the fragment a subject and the activity an observer), and then calling it whenever the `onCreateView` or `onAttach` is done, and then finally calling back to the fragment with the data that needs to be set. However, I need to do this for several fragments so I would have to make a listener for each fragment, which I again think is bad.

Is there any better/easier way to do this?

Comment: What about `FragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()`?

Comment: It worked perfectly! Add the answer and I'll mark that as an accepted answer.

Comment: To pass data to new fragments, you can use arguments: `Bundle args = new Bundle; /* store any data */ newFragment.setArguments(args);`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`FragmentTransaction` isn't applied instantly after calling `commit()`. You may force update manually:

```
...
mFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
```

AFAIK event callbacks' purpose is custom communication with `Fragment` beyond it's usual lifecycle.

Comment: This is useful if you are passing data to fragments. If the fragments are only being used once, use fragment.setArguments(Bundle args) but if you are going to re-use the fragments then it errors so executePendingTransactions() comes in handy so you can call methods/setters on the fragment straight away. Doesn't seem too elegant though.

Answer (score 4):

The *correct* way to do it would be to define an interface for `Activity` classes wishing to display your `Fragment` should implement. That way, on `onAttach` you don't cast to a specific `Activity` but to your interface.

See for instance: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#EventCallbacks

Comment: That's at least a better solution. Even though it doesn't seem perfect, it still seems like a decent way to go. Thank you for the suggestion. EDIT: According to the link you posted (which is the official guides), it seems to be the recommended way.

Comment: @Aske B.: It sure beats trying to tinker with a `Fragment`'s internals

Comment: I get this is the way to communicate from fragment to activity but I think OPs intentions were from activity to fragment. Can this method be applied for the latter case?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `onActivityCreated` to set the values.

Set references in `onCreateView` and then set values to them in `onActivityCreated`.