# LayoutTransition causes Fragment to not show up the second time is created

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-transitions

I have an activity which implements this method:

```
public void pushFragment(MyFragment fragment) {
    stack.add(fragment);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame_layout, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    setTitle(fragment.getTitle(this));
}
```

In a fragment, I have a listview with this onItemClickListener:

```
getAppActivity().pushFragment(anotherFragment);
```

the AnotherFragment onCreateView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    LayoutTransition t = new LayoutTransition();
    container.setLayoutTransition(t);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.another_layout, container, false);

    final ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)rootView.findViewById(R.id.avatar_image_layout);
    vg.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);

    // Stuff

    return rootView;
}
```

On API level >= 19 everything works.
On API 18 and 17 (I didn't test on API 16), the first time I click on the listview item it works. Then I go back and click another time on the item. This time the fragment is created, onActivityCreated and onCreateView etc are called, but the fragment isn't displayed.

EDIT 1:
Commenting random stuff, I've found out that the problem is:

```
LayoutTransition t = new LayoutTransition();
container.setLayoutTransition(t);
```

commenting these two lines solves the problem, but I don't know why and I loose the animation...

Comment: what is your code when pressing the backpress? did you override it and use fragment.popbackstack()?

Comment: Yes, but as you can see from my EDIT 1, the problem is elsewhere

Comment: Im avoiding using animation on my fragment but if you want to, I think this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194311/pop-the-fragment-backstack-without-playing-the-pop-animation

Answer (score 0):

This may vary among APIs, but it is possible that `FragmentTransaction` isn't applied instantly after calling `commit()` ([info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit())).

According to **FragmentTransaction.java**, the `commit()` method states that:

```
 * Schedules a commit of this transaction.  The commit does
 * not happen immediately; it will be scheduled as work on the main thread
 * to be done the next time that thread is ready.
```

In order to make this happening immediately, after the `commit()` method, we call **FragmentManager.java**'s `executePendingTransactions()` ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10865522/2996699)):

```
 * After a {@link FragmentTransaction} is committed with
 * {@link FragmentTransaction#commit FragmentTransaction.commit()}, it
 * is scheduled to be executed asynchronously on the process's main thread.
 * If you want to immediately executing any such pending operations, you
 * can call this function (only from the main thread) to do so.  Note that
 * all callbacks and other related behavior will be done from within this
 * call, so be careful about where this is called from.
```